# Matlab - isbusday and busdate format change

Tags: matlab, function, date

Would you be able to advise how can i change the format of the date the functions isbusday and busdate are using ?

The functions use US date format by default, but I need them to be in European format `dd/mm/yyyy`.

I have attempted to use the code below but it is not working.

```
isbusday('01-01-2015','dd-mm-yyyy')  
busdate('01-01-2015','dd-mm-yyyy',1)
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to convert your string to a `datetime` object. That is where you can control the format:

```
d = datetime('01-01-2015','InputFormat','dd-mm-yyyy');
isbusday(d)
busdate(t)
```

See the documentation: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html and https://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/isbusday.html

Comment: `datetime('01-01-2015','InputFormat','dd-MM-yyyy')`